# iron-router choose different subscriptions in waitOn function - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to decide based on a boolean attribute in a document (`mode`), which subscriptions the user gets, but I have problems with the design approach. If I use `this.data()` and a if clause in the `waitOn` function, I will get the 404 page rendered, because I need first the subscription.

Here is my code:

```
this.route('gamePage', {
        path: '/game/:slug/viewGame/:produceDate?/:releaseDate?',
        onBeforeAction: [memberFilter],
        waitOn: function() {
            var game = this.data();
            if (game.mode) {
                if (this.params.produceDate && this.params.releaseDate) {
                    return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug),
                        Meteor.subscribe('authorsMode', this.params.slug, this.params.produceDate, this.params.releaseDate)];
                } else {
                    return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug), Meteor.subscribe('console', this.params.slug)];
                }
            } else {
                return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug),
                    Meteor.subscribe('authors', this.params.slug)];

            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that directly you would need Iron Router to let you have 2 levels of subscriptions, the first one making data available to the next level of subscription. This feature doesn't exist right now. I've just submitted an [issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/841) to IR repo asking for this feature.

The workaround for this is having different URL for each case, making intermediate redirections:

```
this.route('gamePage', {
  path: '/game/:slug/viewGame/:produceDate?/:releaseDate?',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    var game = this.data();
    var params = {
      slug: this.params.slug,
      produceDate: this.params.produceDate,
      releaseDate: this.params.releaseDate
    }
    if (game.mode) {
      if (this.params.produceDate && this.params.releaseDate) {
        this.redirect('gamePageOption1', params);
      } else {
        this.redirect('gamePageOption2', params);
      }
    } else {
      this.redirect('gamePageOption3', params);
    }
  },
  waitOn: function() {
      return [Meteor.subscribe('games')];
  },
  data: function() {
      return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
  }
}
```

If you are using IR v < 0.9.3 be aware of an issue about intermediate redirections: [ref1](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/824), [ref2](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/828). If this is the case, you have to the redirection inside a `Meteor.defer`:

```
Meteor.defer(function() {
    this.redirect(...)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am not a 100% sure if I understand your approach correctly. So, you suggest to have different routes like `this.route('gamePageOption1')`, `this.route('gamePageOption2')` with the same URL, but with different subscriptions?

Comment: Right, exactly that. One url could be `/game/:slug/viewGame/:produceDate?/:releaseDate?/withMode` an another `/game/:slug/viewGame/:produceDate?/:releaseDate?/noMode`, each with different subscriptions.

Comment: I just want to add, that I found an even better way (for my purpose). Instead of redirecting to different routes, I replaced the statement with `this.subscribe('collectionName', this.params.slug).wait();`. Worked for me!

Comment: That is actually a great solution! thanks for sharing. I suggest adding that comment as an answer and marking that as the accepted answer.